# Conteúdo do footer responsivo

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de ajuda no meu código para tornar as colunas "conteudo" do footer responsivo.
Segue o código abaixo:

```css
*{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;    
}

*.*:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;   
}

body,html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}

footer{
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    clear: both;
    padding: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;    
}

footer:after{
    content: '\00a9  Infogyba Soluções em Ti  ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #8c8c96;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:600;
    font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;  
    text-align: left;
    bottom:0;
    display: block;
}

.endereco,.telefone{
    float:left;
    width: 33.33%;
    border-right: 1px;
    margin-right:15px;  
    border-right-style: outset;  
}

.redes sociais{
    float:left;
    width: 33.33%;  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .endereco, .telefone, .redes-sociais  {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

footer h1,h2{
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:600;
    font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;
    text-align:center; 
    display:inline-block;
}


footer .redes-sociais  a:hover{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotacao; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera (nome da animação)*/
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera (Duração da animação)*/
    animation-name: rotacao; /* nome da animação */
    animation-duration: 2s; /* Duração da animação */
}

@keyframes rotacao {
    from {transform: rotate(1deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@media screen and(max-width:768){
    footer{
        padding-bottom: 3em;   
    }  
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="endereco">
    <h1>Nosso endereço:</h1>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <h1>Rua blalal, 132 - Irajá</h1>
    <h2>Rio de Janeiro Cidade - RJ.</h2>
    <h2>Cep: 21300-630</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="telefone">
    <h1>Consulte-nos:</h1>
    <br>    
    <br>    
    <h2>Telefone: (21)9999-9999</h2>
    <h2>Horário de Atendimento</h2>
    <h2>de Seg a Sexta: 08:00 as 17:00</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="redes-sociais">
    <td><h1>Fale conosco nas Redes Sociais</h1></td>    
    <br>
    <br>    
    <a href="#"><img src="imagens/facebook.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imagens/twitter.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imagens/youtube.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="imagens/google.png"></a>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <br>
    <br>  
    <h1>Email:</h1>
    <h2>blablabla@gmail.com</h2>
  </div>  
</footer>
```

Comment: Eu acho que o problema é as scções estarem com posição absoluta, apague isso e coloque `float:left;` a ver se resulta

Comment: não deu certo exclui o position absolute e coloquei o float:left.

Comment: O mais facil é postar o código relevante em vez de imagens, para ser mais facil quem o quer ajudar testar

Comment: Tem um erro muito grave no seu HTML, está a fechar a `</head>` já depois do `<body>` deve fecha-la emediatamente antes do `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem muita coisa que não precisa e é muito mais simples do que fez, isto é só um exemplo, apenas pegando no seu HTML, pode testar aumentando e diminuindo a janela do browser (navegador) [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/u6cgat0n/), determinei que o footer muda de display quando janela <= 480px:

```css
.endereco, .telefone, .redes-sociais  {
  float:left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .endereco, .telefone, .redes-sociais  {
     float: none;
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="endereco">
<h1>Nosso endereço:</h1>
<br>
<br>    
<h1>Rua blalal, 132 - Irajá</h1>
<h2>Rio de Janeiro Cidade - RJ.</h2>
<h2>Cep: 21300-630</h2>
</div>
<div class="telefone">
<h1>Consulte-nos:</h1>
<br>    
<br>    
<h2>Telefone: (21)9999-9999</h2>
<h2>Horário de Atendimento</h2>
<h2>de Seg a Sexta: 08:00 as 17:00</h2>
</div>
<div class="redes-sociais">
<td><h1>Fale conosco nas Redes Sociais</h1></td>    
<br>
<br>    
<a href="#"><img src="imagens/facebook.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imagens/twitter.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imagens/youtube.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imagens/google.png"></a>
<br>
<br>    
<h1>Email:</h1>
<h2>blablabla@gmail.com</h2>
</div>
</footer>
```

Note que o comprimento das secções (33.33%) é apenas 100% / 3 secções

Comment: Cara muito  obrigado , ficou muito bom, vlw mesmo.

Comment: De nada @ClaytonCampos. Boa sorte